# Players are unable to win in my python game, keeps saying value is higher

Tags: python, linux

I have a guessing game where one player sets the number for the other person to guess, and then the other player tries to guess what the number is, and the game says if the number is higher, or lower than their current guess. My code is pretty messy, and overcomplicated since I am new to Python. But it just recently broke, not letting the player wins. When the player should win, it says that the number is higher. Here's my code:

```py
from random import randint
import getpass

# Allows the user to select the range
guessamount = input("How large do you want the range of numbers to pick be?(Limit is 420): ")
if int(guessamount) >= int(420):
    guessamount = 420

# Allows player 1 to select the answer for player 2 to guess
answer = getpass.getpass("Player 1 select the answer (The answer will not show up while typing):")
if int(answer) >= int(guessamount):
    answer = guessamount
attempts = 5

while attempts != 0:
    guess = input("Guess a number between 1-" + str(guessamount) + ": ")

    if answer == int(guess):
        attempts = 0
    else:
        attempts -= 1

        if int(guess) > int(answer):
            print ("You suck at this game. The answer is lower than " + str(guess))
        else:
            print ("You suck at this game. The answer is higher than " + str(guess))

if answer == int(guess):
    print("You won the game! The answer was " + str(answer))
else:
    print("You ran out of attempts. The number was " + str(answer))
```

Comment: Sometimes you convert `answer` to int, and sometimes you don't. You can't compare strings to int. Also, is your final test indented correctly? It's not executing within the while loop, as written.

Comment: @jarmod, did I convert the answer to int somewhere where I shouldn't have?

Comment: I think I found the issue, let me see.

Comment: @jarmod I found the issue, some parts weren't int. look at the answer posted below for the full solution, thanks 

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! I changed it so the player inserts the answer instead of it being random. And I forgot to change the numbers to int.

Thanks @jarmod for helping.